# Is this statement similar to law of total expectations true?

Tags: probability-theory, conditional-expectation

I believe that $\mathbb{E}_x(x \mathbb{E}_{y|x}(y|x))=\mathbb{E}_y(xy)$, and that the proof is as follows for the discrete case.

\begin{align}
\mathbb{E}_x(x\mathbb{E}_{y|x}(y|x))&=\mathbb{E}_x(x\sum_y y\:p(y|x))\\
&=\sum_y xy\sum_x p(y|x)p(x)\textrm{ Fubini as in iterated expectations}\\
&=\sum_y xy \:p(y)\\
&=\mathbb{E}_y(xy)
\end{align}

This seems right to me, but I wanted to check.

Comment: Indeed we have $E[XE[Y|X]] = E[E[XY|X]] = E[XY]$.  I don't know what you mean by $E_Y[XY]$.

Comment: The interchange of summation over $x$ and $y$ doesn't look right.

Comment: Yes, in the direction of Theoretical Economist's observation, I see that your calculation has $x$ as a summation variable, but eventually it somehow pulls it out from its own sum, resulting in a dangling $x$, so that you get an incorrect expression $\sum_y xy p(y)$ that you know is incorrect since it is a function of $x$.

Comment: The confusion between random variables and their values, often seen on this site, is at its worst here... With the concrete consequence that the OP is reduced to manipulating meaningless symbols, hoping that the result is somehow "right". :-( A first step towards light and reason could be to get rid of the indices $x$ and $y$ in the expectation symbols, which are all quite (worse than) useless.

Comment: I get your idea with indexing the expectations; in some (rare) cases it may make it easier to recognize what to integrate. But *always* indexing seems awkward and confusing at best. 
With your notation, $E_x(x\sum_y y \, p(y\mid x)) = \sum_x x\sum_y y \, p(y\mid x) p(x) = \sum_x\sum_y xy \, p(y\mid x) p(x)$. Recognize $p(y\mid x)p(x) = p(y,x)$. Your final expectation is not on $Y$ but on $XY$.